# How to get good performance when writing a list of integers from 1 to 10 million to a file?

Tags: linux, performance, haskell

### question

I want a program that will write a sequence like,

```
1
...
10000000
```

to a file. *What's the simplest code one can write, and get decent performance*? My intuition is that there is some lack-of-buffering problem. My C code runs at 100 MB/s, whereas by reference the Linux command line utility `dd` runs at <strike>9 GB/s</strike> 3 GB/s (sorry for the imprecision, see comments -- I'm more interested in the big picture orders-of-magnitude though).

One would think this would be a solved problem by now ... i.e. any modern compiler would make it immediate to write such programs that perform reasonably well ...

### C code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int len = 10000000;
    for (int a = 1; a <= len; a++) {
        printf ("%d\n", a);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I'm compiling with `clang -O3`. A performance skeleton which calls `putchar('\n')` 8 times gets comparable performance.

### Haskell code

A naiive Haskell implementation runs at 13 MiB/sec, compiling with `ghc -O2 -optc-O3 -optc-ffast-math -fllvm -fforce-recomp -funbox-strict-fields`. (I haven't recompiled my libraries with `-fllvm`, perhaps I need to do that.) Code:

```
import Control.Monad
main = forM [1..10000000 :: Int] $ \j -> putStrLn (show j)
```

My best stab with Haskell runs even slower, at 17 MiB/sec. The problem is I can't find a good way to convert `Vector`'s into `ByteString`'s (perhaps there's a solution using iteratees?).

```
import qualified Data.Vector.Unboxed as V
import Data.Vector.Unboxed (Vector, Unbox, (!))

writeVector :: (Unbox a, Show a) => Vector a -> IO ()
writeVector v = V.mapM_ (System.IO.putStrLn . show) v

main = writeVector (V.generate 10000000 id)
```

**It seems that writing `ByteString`'s is fast**, as demonstrated by this code, writing an equivalent number of characters,

```
import Data.ByteString.Char8 as B
main = B.putStrLn (B.replicate 76000000 '\n')
```

This gets 1.3 GB/s, which isn't as fast as `dd`, but obviously much better.

Comment: Have you tried a buffered solution yet? E.g. write 512 numbers at a time, which plus newlines = 1024 bytes. Then try multiples of 1024, and see if it improves performance?

Comment: How is that dd runs at 9GB/s ?! SATA throughput is 3-6 Gb/s (Giga bit, not Byte)

Comment: A `putStrLn . show` for each number is terribly slow. A simple `main = putStr . unlines . map show $ [1 :: Int .. 10000000]` runs here about thrice as fast as your first Haskell version.

Comment: I wonder how much overhead is going into encoding the `String` on its way out to the handle. Also, have you checked what happens with `BlockBuffering` instead of `LineBuffering`?

Comment: @FerminSilva he isn't comparing apples to apples. Not to mention he talks about writing to a file then posts code that prints to the console.

Comment: @FerminSilva, @AndrewFinnell: you are right, I'm not being so precise. I was writing to ramdisk, and supposed that this was not different than `/dev/null`. See output here: http://pastebin.com/SRiDYa9r . I'm more interested in the big performance picture.

Comment: @DanielFischer, nice!! Still 1/3 of the C version, but better!

Comment: @DanielWagner, Thanks for the suggestion, it didn't seem to help though (I tried 1M, 1K, and using file handles instead of stdout). Code: `main = do { hSetBuffering stdout (BlockBuffering (Just (2 ^ 20))); putStr . unlines . map show $ [1 :: Int .. 10000000] }`

Comment: @RoryHunter, I'm not sure what library to use. It's been a while since I've done low-level stuff. Some BufferedWriter Java code gets 75 MiB / second [ http://pastebin.com/rrWhqEM3 ].

Comment: @AndrewFinnell Perhaps on Windows, writing to the console is not the same as writing to a file, but I think on Linux it's pretty much equivalent. As you can see from an earlier comment, it doesn't seem to affect `dd` performance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Some completely unscientific benchmarking first:

All programmes have been compiled with the default optimisation level (-O3 for gcc, -O2 for GHC) and run with

```
time ./prog > outfile
```

As a baseline, the C programme took 1.07s to produce a ~76MB (78888897 bytes) file, roughly 70MB/s throughput.

1. The "naive" Haskell programme (`forM [1 .. 10000000] $ \j -> putStrLn (show j)`) took 8.64s, about 8.8MB/s.
2. The same with `forM_` instead of `forM` took 5.64s, about 13.5MB/s.
3. The `ByteString` version from dflemstr's answer took 9.13s, about 8.3MB/s.
4. The `Text` version from dflemstr's answer took 5.64s, about 13.5MB/s.
5. The `Vector` version from the question took 5.54s, about 13.7MB/s.
6. `main = mapM_ (C.putStrLn . C.pack . show) $ [1 :: Int .. 10000000]`, where `C` is `Data.ByteString.Char8`, took 4.25s, about 17.9MB/s.
7. `putStr . unlines . map show $ [1 :: Int .. 10000000]` took 3.06s, about 24.8MB/s.
8. A manual loop,

   ```
   main = putStr $ go 1
     where
       go :: Int -> String
       go i
           | i > 10000000 = ""
           | otherwise = shows i . showChar '\n' $ go (i+1)
   ```

   took 2.32s, about 32.75MB/s.
9. `main = putStrLn $ replicate 78888896 'a'` took 1.15s, about 66MB/s.
10. `main = C.putStrLn $ C.replicate 78888896 'a'` where `C` is `Data.ByteString.Char8`, took 0.143s, about 530MB/s, roughly the same figures for lazy `ByteString`s.

#### What can we learn from that?

First, don't use `forM` or `mapM` unless you really want to collect the results. Performancewise, that sucks.

Then, `ByteString` output can be very fast (10.), but if the construction of the `ByteString` to output is slow (3.), you end up with slower code than the naive `String` output.

What's so terrible about 3.? Well, all the involved `String`s are very short. So you get a list of

```
Chunk "1234567" Empty
```

and between any two such, a `Chunk "\n" Empty` is put, then the resulting list is concatenated, which means all these `Empty`s are tossed away when a `... (Chunk "1234567" (Chunk "\n" (Chunk "1234568" (...))))` is built. That's a lot of wasteful construct-deconstruct-reconstruct going on. Speed comparable to that of the `Text` and the fixed "naive" `String` version can be achieved by `pack`ing to strict `ByteString`s and using `fromChunks` (and `Data.List.intersperse` for the newlines). Better performance, slightly better than 6., can be obtained by eliminating the costly singletons. If you glue the newlines to the `String`s, using `\k -> shows k "\n"` instead of `show`, the concatenation has to deal with half as many slightly longer `ByteString`s, which pays off.

I'm not familiar enough with the internals of either text or vector to offer more than a semi-educated guess concerning the reasons for the observed performance, so I'll leave them out. Suffice it to say that the performance gain is marginal at best compared to the fixed naive `String` version.

Now, 6. shows that `ByteString` output is faster than `String` output, enough that in this case the additional work of `pack`ing is more than compensated. However, don't be fooled by that to believe that is always so. If the `String`s to pack are long, the packing can take more time than the `String` output.

But ten million invocations of `putStrLn`, be it the `String` or the `ByteString` version, take a lot of time. It's faster to grab the `stdout` `Handle` just once and construct the output `String` in non-IO code. `unlines` already does well, but we still suffer from the construction of the list `map show [1 .. 10^7]`. Unfortunately, the compiler didn't manage to eliminate that (but it eliminated `[1 .. 10^7]`, that's already pretty good). So let's do it ourselves, leading to 8. That's not too terrible, but still takes more than twice as long as the C programme.

One can make a faster Haskell programme by going low-level and directly filling `ByteString`s without going through `String` via `show`, but I don't know if the C speed is reachable. Anyway, that low-level code isn't very pretty, so I'll spare you what I have, but sometimes one has to get one's hands dirty if speed matters.

Comment: Great answer, thanks! I will keep in mind `forM_`, etc. in the future. Funny that the manual recursion is faster than e.g. the blaze-builder code I have below. OTOH, for a "check mark", I am looking for 10x the performance of my naiive C code, not 1/2 of it :). Don't spend too much time though ... it's funny how this simple question can drive one mad :). I'll try writing a mmap version soon...

Comment: Hmm, 10× the performance of the C? Scratch that, I think. On my humble machine, I can get about 200 million divisions per second; getting the digits of the numbers to 10M takes about 60 million divisions. If the compiler replaces the division by a multiply and a shift, that would give maybe a threefold speedup. You'd still be at 10% of the naive C time just for getting digits, without any (Byte)String construction and output. If you get really ugly, you could probably beat it, but not by such a margin, I believe.

Comment: You might be right; I fallaciously assuming that it was blocked on IO because the IO skeleton (8 calls to `putchar`, generating a rougly equivalently-sized file) took about the same time. I wrote a test skeleton of the computation part though, and it does seem significantly faster (around 400 MiB/s) [ http://pastebin.com/5wS0YPs2 ].

Comment: Yes, that's a good four times faster than the printf version for me. I would have expected the I/O-less thing to be rather faster, but still, the majority of time is spent for I/O. However, the computation time is a hard bottom below which you can't get. For fast throughput, you need easy to come by data.

Comment: It's definitely not blocked on IO.  I also get huge improvement by just doing the IO skeleton.  The bottleneck is integer to bytestring conversion.

Comment: @Gabriel The comments before referred to the C program. That's not entirely IO-bound either, but a lot of its time is spent doing IO. For Haskell, we have several bottlenecks that contribute in varying degrees in the different programs. The `Int -> (Byte)String` conversion, the composition of the output `(Byte)String`, the many calls to `putStrLn`, the slowness of String-I/O. The conversion is common to all, each of the others can be eliminated or greatly mitigated with relative ease. So yes, once you've done something about the others, the conversion becomes the or one of the bottlenecks.

Answer (score 3):

Using lazy byte strings gives you some buffering, because the string will be written instantly and more numbers will only be produced as they are needed. This code shows the basic idea (there might be some optimizations that could be made):

```
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8 as ByteString

main =
  ByteString.putStrLn .
  ByteString.intercalate (ByteString.singleton '\n') .
  map (ByteString.pack . show) $
  ([1..10000000] :: [Int])
```

I still use `String`s for the numbers here, which leads to horrible slowdowns. If we switch to the [`text`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/text) library instead of the [`bytestring`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/bytestring) library, we get access to "native" show functions for ints, and can do this:

```
import Data.Monoid
import Data.List
import Data.Text.Lazy.IO as Text
import Data.Text.Lazy.Builder as Text
import Data.Text.Lazy.Builder.Int as Text

main :: IO ()
main =
  Text.putStrLn .
  Text.toLazyText .
  mconcat .
  intersperse (Text.singleton '\n') .
  map Text.decimal $
  ([1..10000000] :: [Int])
```

I don't know how you are measuring the "speed" of these programs (with the `pv` tool?) but I imagine that one of these procedures will be the fastest trivial program you can get.

Comment: Also with ByteString you could use blaze-builder similarly to how you use text's Builder

Comment: @dflemstr, very nice looking solutions, thanks! Performance-wise, I get 17.7 MB/s for the latter (4.3 seconds on my machine). It seems GHC isn't completely optimizing away the lists, since using `Data.Vector` yields further improvement [ http://pastebin.com/62b3YK4s ].

Comment: @alternative, that seems significantly faster than dflemstr's answer, but not so much faster than Daniel Fischer's comment (yet). Current throughput is 40 MiB/s using this code [ http://pastebin.com/de8xA3n5 ]

Answer (score 3):

If you are going for maximum performance, then it helps to take a holistic view; i.e., you want to write a function that maps from `[Int]` to series of system calls that write chunks of memory to a file.

Lazy bytestrings are good representation for a sequence of chunks of memory. Mapping a lazy bytestring to a series of systems calls that write chunks of memory is what `L.hPut` is doing (assuming an `import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as L`). Hence, we just need a means to efficiently construct the corresponding lazy bytestring. This is what lazy bytestring builders are good at. With the new bytestring builder (here is the [API documentation](http://people.inf.ethz.ch/meiersi/downloads/private/bytestring-0.10.0.0-public/)), the following code does the job.

```
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy          as L
import           Data.ByteString.Lazy.Builder       (toLazyByteString, charUtf8)
import           Data.ByteString.Lazy.Builder.ASCII (intDec)
import           Data.Foldable                      (foldMap)
import           Data.Monoid                        (mappend)
import           System.IO                          (openFile, IOMode(..))

main :: IO ()
main = do
    h <- openFile "/dev/null" WriteMode
    L.hPut h $ toLazyByteString $
        foldMap ((charUtf8 '\n' `mappend`) . intDec) [1..10000000]
```

Note that I output to `/dev/null` to avoid interference by the disk driver. The effort of moving the data to the OS remains the same. On my machine, the above code runs in 0.45 seconds, which is 12 times faster than the 5.4 seconds of your original code. This implies a throughput of 168 MB/s. We can squeeze out an additional 30% speed (220 MB/s) using bounded encodings].

```
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy.Builder.BasicEncoding as E

L.hPut h $ toLazyByteString $
    E.encodeListWithB 
        ((\x -> (x, '\n')) E.>$< E.intDec `E.pairB` E.charUtf8) 
        [1..10000000]
```

Their syntax looks a bit quirky because a `BoundedEncoding a` specifies the conversion of a Haskell value of type `a` to a bounded-length sequence of bytes such that the bound can be *computed at compile-time*. This allows functions such as `E.encodeListWithB` to perform some additional optimizations for implementing the actual filling of the buffer. See the the documentation of `Data.ByteString.Lazy.Builder.BasicEncoding` in the above link to the API documentation (phew, stupid hyperlink limit for new users) for more information.

Here is the [source of all my benchmarks](https://gist.github.com/2487861).

The conclusion is that we can get very good performance from a declarative solution provided that we understand the cost model of our implementation and use the right datastructures. Whenever constructing a packed sequence of values (e.g., a sequence of bytes represented as a bytestring), then the right datastructure to use is a bytestring `Builder`.